# Is a non Hausdorff locally compact space necessarily regular?

Tags: general-topology

> Is a non Hausdorff locally compact space necessarily regular?

Please help me in understanding this concept.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an infinite set with the cofinite topology. It is T1 but cannot be regular or normal as no pair of non-empty open sets can be disjoint. Every subspace is compact.